# Is there an algorithm to compute a Belyi map for the Riemann surface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, graph-theory, galois-theory, riemann-surfaces

Let $y^2=x^5-x-1$ be an affine model of a projective complex curve, is there an algorithm to compute the Belyi map (preferably of small degree), i.e., map to the projective line ramified only at $\{0,1,\infty\}$.

In my attempts to do this by hand, I get ramification at 4 points and, subsequently, using Shabat polynomial will skyrocket the degree of the map. Is there a way to avoid increasing the degree to thousands or hundreds? I have  $\beta=h\circ g\ \circ f$, where $f$ is projection on $x$, $g=x^5-x-1$ and $h=\frac{( 12500 x + 18750 x^2 + 12500 x^3 + 3125 x^4)}{-2869}$. $\beta$ gives ramification at four points $\{0,1, \infty, \frac{3125}{2869}\}$. Also, it is possible to use $g=x^5-x$ with different $h$, but the Shabat polynomial will still be of very big degree....

After some work, I have obtained maps: $f$ projection on $x$ ramified at five roots of $x^5-x-1$, $g(z)=z^5-z$ ramified at $\pm \frac{4}{5\sqrt[4]{5}}$, $h=z^4$ ramified at $0$. As a result $\beta=h\circ g\circ f$ is ramified at $\{0, \frac{256}{3125}, 1, \infty\}$, which is slightly better. Using Shabat map $\frac{m}{m+n}=\frac{256}{256+2869}$ gives $\alpha(z)=\frac{(m+n)^{m+n}}{m^mn^n}z^m(1-z)^n=\frac{(3125)^{3125}}{256^{256} 2869^{2869} }z^{256}(1-z)^{2869} $. The resulting map $\alpha\circ\beta$ is of huge degree....

Comment: First of all, there are a lot of distinct Belyi maps for a given curve. I guess there is not a method to compute the one of smallest degree, unless you have a "special curve" (modular, large automorphism, etc). Usually the maps have very high degree, since there is a finite number of curves with a given genus $>0$ and degree of the Belyi map.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to figure out whether it is possible to obtain a Belyi map (out of many possible) with a small degree (not necessarily the smallest). In the case of this hyperelliptic curve, endomorphism algebra of its Jacobian is absolutely simple, hence no large automorphisms. As you mentioned, the case of many automorphisms is treated in many sources (Wolfart).

Comment: @Xarles  If by "method" you mean algorithm, then I just wanted to point out that there  is an algorithm to compute a Belyi map of smallest degree on any curve (which is not always very practical though): https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.00125.pdf

Comment: Possibly of interest: Vincent Beffara's "Dessins d'enfants for analysts" https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00244 featuring lots of pictures

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Thank you. I have tried to follow the algorithm and can see why it is not practical... However, the bounds give some hope

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar When I was writing that sentence I said to myself that that was probably wrong (so one could make up a very impractical algorithm to compute it, may be just computing all the dessins for a given degree and genus, and so on), but I am happy I wrote that, so you mentioned your nice paper.